# Given a sequence of numbers how to identify the missing numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery, gaps-and-islands, gaps-in-data

I would like to get all missing numbers in a sequence of numbers.
Just wondering if there is a better approach than below?

```
SELECT x
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT x,
           LAG(x,1) OVER ( ORDER BY x ) prev_x
      FROM 
       ( SELECT * FROM
        ( SELECT 1 AS x ),
        ( SELECT 2 AS x ),
        ( SELECT 3 AS x ),
        ( SELECT 4 AS x ),
        ( SELECT 5 AS x ),
        ( SELECT 6 AS x ),
        ( SELECT 8 AS x ),
        ( SELECT 10 AS x ),
        ( SELECT 11 AS x )
       )
  ) 
 WHERE x-prev_x > 1;
```

Comment: it `really` depends on which flavor of sql you are in with this! based on tags you added  - i would assume this is for BigQuery? please confirm or clarify!

Comment: any solution is appreciated...

Comment: SO prefers specific questions that have a particular answer. Open questions (too many possible answers) are discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***shortest*** solution in **Postgres** is with standard SQL [**`EXCEPT`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-union.html):

```sql
WITH tbl(x) AS (SELECT unnest ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11}'::int[]))
-- the CTE provides a temp table - might be an actual table instead
SELECT generate_series(min(x), max(x)) FROM tbl
EXCEPT ALL
TABLE  tbl;
```

The set-returning function [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) is Postgres specific and just the shortest syntax to provide your set of numbers as table.

Also works with duplicates or NULL values in the data.

`TABLE tbl` is (standard SQL!) short syntax for `SELECT * FROM tbl`:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM in psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from-in-psql/30276023#30276023)

Related (with more explanation):

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)
- [How to check a sequence efficiently for used and unused values in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684374/how-to-check-a-sequence-efficiently-for-used-and-unused-values-in-postgresql/32686099#32686099)

Comment: I am fine with this solution for postgres. Is there any way to implement this without using the functions..?

Answer (score 3):

Let me be honest with you!
Any another working solution will be better then presented in question  - for one simple reason  - it is wrong! it does not return missing numbers at all! it rather shows number after next gap. that's all (hope you will appreciate that I opened your eyes on this)

Now, about better solution(s) - there are tons of options for you to pursue.
Note: below options for BigQuery ONLY!

> Option 1

**BigQuery Standard SQL** - see [How to Enable Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS x UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS x UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS x UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 AS x UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 AS x UNION ALL
  SELECT 11 AS x
),
nums AS (
  SELECT num 
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY((SELECT MIN(x) FROM YourTable), (SELECT MAX(x) FROM YourTable))) AS num
)
SELECT num FROM nums
LEFT JOIN YourTable ON num = x
WHERE x IS NULL
ORDER BY num
```

> Option 2

**BigQuery Legacy SQL** you can try below (here you need to set start/min and end/max values inside select expression for nums table

```
SELECT num FROM (
  SELECT num FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS num, * 
    FROM (FLATTEN((SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 11, '.'),'') AS h FROM (SELECT NULL)), h))
  ) WHERE num BETWEEN 1 AND 11
) AS nums
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT x FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS x),
    (SELECT 2 AS x),
    (SELECT 3 AS x),
    (SELECT 6 AS x),
    (SELECT 8 AS x),
    (SELECT 10 AS x),
    (SELECT 11 AS x)
) AS YourTable
ON num = x
WHERE x IS NULL
```

> Option 3

**BigQuery Legacy SQL** - if you want not to have dependency on min and max and have needs in setting those values  - you can use below solution  - it only requires to set high enough max to accommodate your expected growth (I put 1000 for example)

```
SELECT num FROM (
  SELECT num FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS num, * 
    FROM (FLATTEN((SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 1000, '.'),'') AS h FROM (SELECT NULL)), h))
  ) WHERE num BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
) AS nums
LEFT JOIN YourTable
ON num = x
WHERE x IS NULL
AND num BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(x) FROM YourTable) AND (SELECT MAX(x) FROM YourTable)
```

> Option 4  (for some reason - my favorite so far)

**BigQuery Standard SQL** - without explicit joins

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS x UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS x UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS x UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 AS x UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 AS x UNION ALL
  SELECT 11 AS x
)
SELECT num
FROM (SELECT x, LEAD(x) OVER(ORDER BY x) AS next_x FROM YourTable),  
     UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(x + 1,next_x - 1)) AS num
WHERE next_x - x > 1
ORDER BY x
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But what if the table(x) keeps increasing...?

Comment: use first solution in my answer (standard sql)  - it takes care of this!

Comment: added for bq legacy sql so it takes care of it too

Comment: In the first solution I am trying to implement using postgresql but those functions do not work...  Tried using sqlfiddle link as below.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/19495/4

Comment: Option 2 works fine and its limited ... In option 1 cte's do not work on Bigquery.. Just ran it now...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123085/discussion-between-soaddict-and-mikhail-berlyant).

Comment: to run option1 you should enable standard sql - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql

Comment: and if option 2 works for yo  - it means option 3 should also work for you!

Comment: Ravi, I hope you at least was able to finally run those in BigQuery! even though looks like you were more interested in postgresql version. otherwise i just wasted my time :o(

Answer (score 1):

Your query can be written much more succinctly like so:

```
SELECT x
FROM (
    SELECT x,
           lag(x, 1) OVER ( ORDER BY x ) prev_x
    FROM ( VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (8), (10), (11) ) v(x)
) sub
WHERE x-prev_x > 1;
```

This will return the next highest value after a miss (`8, 10`), not the missing values themselves (`7, 9`). But of course you do not have the values handy.

If you know the range of values in the sequence, then you can use this:

```
SELECT s.x
FROM generate_series(<<min>>, <<max>>) s(x)
LEFT JOIN my_table t ON s.x = t.x
WHERE t.x IS NULL;
```

This returns the actual missing values.

If you do not know the range of values, you need to add a sub-query:

```
SELECT s.x
FROM ( SELECT min(x), max(x) FROM my_table ) r
JOIN generate_series(r.min, r.max) s(x) ON true
LEFT JOIN my_table t ON s.x = t.x
WHERE t.x IS NULL;
```

Alternatively, instead of a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT x
FROM ( SELECT min(x), max(x) FROM my_table ) r,
     generate_series(r.min, r.max) s(x)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table t WHERE t.x = s.x);
```

Comment: This is a solid answer. I don't see a reason for downvotes. Minor confusing detail: the OP's example omits 7 and 9 (not 8 and 9).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter A down-vote is only a click away (but I did mess up the parentheses in the VALUES clause in my initial answer). Thanks for the thumbs-up. List of values corrected.